# [Visual Studio]How can I update a foreign web reference?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, web-reference

I have a server where I use Microsoft CRM. MS CRM auto-generate web references. I take over someone else's application code (an application which connects to CRM). I expect to develop on my local machine, but the references they gave me are not up to date. I want to update them using the right-click/update on the reference.

But it requires a name/pass authentication. If I connect to the server normally, I can see the aspx page by the browser, but using the same link in my VS reference, I can't update with my server connection infos, it won't let me.

How do I have to proceed to update the references?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Update Service Reference" in VS actually uses [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) (or [wsdl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28VS.71%29.aspx) which was the tool pre-WCF), to generate the proxy classes. Both have command line options that let you specify your authentication details, so you can use command-line to generate the service reference while specifying your credentials.